# All actions in my activity fails to load

Tags: bug, profile-page

If I go to my Stack Overflow profile -> my activity -> all sections, I am getting the below response:

[image]

The rest of the site seems to be loading fine. The other tabs are working.
It seems if I manage to get link of subsections in "all actions", they work. My activity history seems to be breaking the page.

Comment: That looks like a query is using a suboptimal query plan. repro-ed. Adding a subcategory "solves" it: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4826457/suraj-rao?tab=activity&sort=suggestions but don't click on "All" ;)

Comment: Link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4826457/suraj-rao?tab=activity click on all.

Comment: @rene yes subcategory is working. and "all" tab in all actions fails. SO is hinting I am spending way too much time here

Comment: Probably related: https://twitter.com/tarynpivots/status/1366759308264837122

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Your activity page (tab all) loads fine for me, and so does my own. Perhaps the issue was transient?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it seems to be working now though we don't know the cause for certain. Should I delete this post?

Comment: @SurajRao: if you want to, I've simply closed it now as 'no longer reproducible'. I suspect that it was caused by heavy database load at the time (I know the devs were moving a int column to int64 at the time, that could easily cause some timeouts here and there).

Comment: @MartijnPieters This issue is happening again https://stackoverflow.com/users/4826457/suraj-rao?tab=activity&sort=all

Comment: @SurajRao: not for me, at least.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it was occuring today. Now its working again. Intermittent issue...