# What's wrong with my flag?

Tags: discussion, flags

I had my flag declined. The question was a "Do my homework" one. I couldn't find any flag that is appropriate:

- Spam: it was not spam
- Rude or abusive: the OP literally wrote: "Write a program that does...", but I think this is rude or abusive. As far as I understood this is used when the OP is bullying, discriminating...
- Needs improvement: from my POV this can't be improved, as the OP has only copy-pasted the text of his exercise
- A duplicate: it might have been a duplicate, but that wasn't the point
- Very low quality: in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95581/the-limits-to-a-very-low-quality-answer/167641#167641) it is written "Questions that don't show any research effort"
- In need of moderator intervention: that's what I chose and what has been declined.

My flag comment: "I don't really know how to flag this. The OP talks like a teacher that gives the homework. He doesn't show any attempt of trying to find a solution by its own. I think this should be closed or rewritten."

The moderator answer: "declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)?"

After ten minutes someone else have flagged this question and it got closed.

How should I have flagged this question and why I got that reply? In case I have chosen the wrong category, why the moderator still haven't accepted the flag or at least haven't told me what category I should choose?

Comment: Needs improvement ->" Needs more focus"/"Needs details or clarity" would do. Needs improvement meaning OP has to do the improvement...

Comment: Mod flags are for very special cases that require their attention. This is not one of them. A regular flag could have been enough. Anyway the mod gave you a link to a page with ***lots*** of information about this including many more links with information. As stated, familiarize yourself with flagging. Lastly, he shouldn't have accepted it or else you wouldn't come here and keep using the wrong flags ;)

Comment: Please note that homework question [are not by definition off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404053).

Comment: *Needs improvement: from my POV this can't be improved...* When flagging, go by what should happen to a question to make it on-topic and answerable. If it would have been on-topic if they'd included details about where they're stuck and what they tried then that's the flag you should use even if you suspect they haven't tried anything.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. As I understood by @Ivar comment, this, as an homework question, should not be flagged. I may flag for other reasons, like if the OP doesn't give enough details. But still: why the other user could flag it and a moderator closed the question?

Comment: @lax48 To be clear, I didn't say that homework questions are always on-topic. They can still be off-topic, but not for the mere fact of being a question about homework. I can't really tell if the question you are talking about is on- or off-topic, because you haven't shared it.

Comment: @lax48 Because users are not a consistent body. There has never been any proper on-boarding of new users and as a result a lot of moderation is done by what an individual *believes* to be a rule, not what the meta community agreed on.

Comment: @lax48 just to note on the question you flagged - a user *voted* to close the question with a custom reason - the question itself was never closed but the OP self-deleted shortly after

Comment: @JonClements thank you very much. Now it makes sense: I have seen the message of stackoverflow saying the post has been closed, but I haven't thought about it have been self-deleted. Thanks also for all the others: now I know what I should and should not flag more clearly! Lastly I'm sorry I couldn't post the question, but as it has been closed I can't see that either

Comment: @lax48 I think you may still be confused about the differences in closed and deleted. You can still see a post if it has been closed. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405704/all-actions-in-my-activity-fails-to-load) is currently closed. But it is not deleted. It also has the added "[closed]" in its title. A post closed as a duplicate will have "[duplicate]" added to its title.

Comment: @Scratte Thank you, you are right! I didn't know that! I can see that the title has not the "[closed]" at the end. The reason why I thought that it was closed, even if the title doesn't have "[closed]", is that when I try to open the link it says Page not found. The same thing happens if I try to open a question with "[closed]" in the title. So I wrongly understood that a closed question is also a deleted one. Maybe the question with "[closed]" in the title has been closed and then the OP removed it. So now I know that I have still lots of things to learn about this site. Thank you again!

Comment: @lax48 "Page not found" means it was deleted :) JonClements said that the Question author deleted it. Which they can do under some circumstances. When you reach 10000 reputation points, you'll be able to see deleted posts. Then the page will never give you "Page not found". If you go to the [Help Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66PI.png) and then click on "View a full list of privileges you can earn" you'll be able to read about what users can do at different reputation levels. I recommend also reading *all* the other pages for a better understanding of Stack Overflow :)

Comment: May I ask why you thought the "very low quality" flag wasn't appropriate? Surely a homework dump counts as "doesn't show any research effort"?

Comment: @F1Krazy Sure. I think that wasn't appropriate because it wasn't badly formatted or badly explained, but it was "do this for me". If you read the post linked in my question, "Questions that don't show any research effort" is under the "you should not used" (now that I read again I understand why it is ambiguous). As Ivar pointed out in his comment, in StackOverflow you shouldn't flag at all homework posts just because they don't show any search effort. The only thing you should do is to down vote (I discovered that it was written in the tooltip of the down vote)

Comment: @F1Krazy that is a reason to downvote. VLQ is not meant for bad questions. VLQ is meant for “this post is a dumpster fire but not spam or abusive and no amount of editing will turn it into a question please come and put it out of its misery now!” If the post is a readable attempt at posting a question in English, do not flag the post as VLQ.